# Data travel from DAL to MVC View

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

ASP.NET MVC4

I have Business layer DLL which communicates to my DAL and retrieves classes like:

```
public class ProductionParameter
    {
        public string CompanyCode { get; set; }
        public string UnitCode { get; set; }
        public string ItemDescriptionLocal { get; set; }
        public string ItemDescriptionEnglish { get; set; }
        public string ConsumedItemDescriptionLocal { get; set; }
        public string ConsumedItemDescriptionEnglish { get; set; }
        public string LotCategory1Description { get; set; }
        public string LotCategory2Description { get; set; }
        public string LotCategory3Description { get; set; }
        public string LotCategory1Code { get; set; }
        public string LotCategory2Code { get; set; }
        public string LotCategory3Code { get; set; }
        public string LineCode { get; set; }
        public string LineCodeDisplay { get; set; }

        public List<Pallet> PalletsProduced { get; set; }

    }
```

My controller gets the above info but my View doesnt need all the above.

For example lets say i get 3 production parameters classes that each one has 20 Pallets. It means that each productionparameter has 20 pallets produced.

I want to show to my MVC View consolidated data for each production parameter.

How i do it correctly?

**Standard Case:**

Do i create in Models a class with exactly the info i need for the view and then define this class in the @model directive?

**AJAX:**

What changes if i want to make this via AJAX? My AJAX call will return the consolidated data or the full data and let AngularJS or Jquery make the consolidation on the client?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `ViewModel`s keeping your business logic separate from Views.A `ViewModel` represents data that you want to have displayed on your view/page.

Lets say that you have an `ProductionParameterclass` which contains the following properties:

```
public class ProductionParameter
{
   public string CompanyCode { get; set; }
   public string UnitCode { get; set; }
   public string ItemDescriptionLocal { get; set; }
   public string ItemDescriptionEnglish { get; set; }
   public string ConsumedItemDescriptionLocal { get; set; }
   public string ConsumedItemDescriptionEnglish { get; set; }
   public string LotCategory1Description { get; set; }
   public string LotCategory2Description { get; set; }
   public string LotCategory3Description { get; set; }
   public string LotCategory1Code { get; set; }
   public string LotCategory2Code { get; set; }
   public string LotCategory3Code { get; set; }
   public string LineCode { get; set; }
   public string LineCodeDisplay { get; set; }
   public List<Pallet> PalletsProduced { get; set; }
}
```

View models differ from domain models in that view models only contain the data (represented by properties) that you want to use on your view.

Suppose, you want to display only following properties on the view, then your ViewModel can be

```
 public class ProductionParameterViewModel
 {
    public string CompanyCode { get; set; }
    public string UnitCode { get; set; }
    public string ItemDescriptionLocal { get; set; }
    public string ItemDescriptionEnglish { get; set; }
    public string ConsumedItemDescriptionLocal { get; set; }
    public string ConsumedItemDescriptionEnglish { get; set; }
    public string LineCodeDisplay { get; set; }
    public List<Pallet> PalletsProduced { get; set; }
  }
```

Then , on your View, you can use it as below:

```
@model MyProject.ViewModels.ProductionParameterViewModel
```

**Edit:**

If you have two models, then you can put them in a single model as below:

```
public class ViewModel1
{

}

public class ViewModel2
{

}

public class MyAggregateModel
{
   public ViewModel1 Model1 { get; set;}

   public ViewModel2 Model2 { get; set;}
}
```

Comment: Nice. And what i should do if i want to return 2 sets of data? I mean 2 different ViewModelClasses?

Comment: I see. So i pass MyAggregateModel to my view and everythign is fine..And this goes also with the Ajax way of things

Comment: @e4rthdog Yes, all other things remain the same.

Answer (score 4):

> Standard Case:
>
> Do i create in Models a class with exactly the info i need for the
>   view and then define this class in the @model directive?

Yes, that's exactly what you should do. You define a view model with only the properties requires by your view. Then your controller action will aggregate one or more domain models into the view model and pass it to the view.

> AJAX:
>
> What changes if i want to make this via AJAX? My AJAX call will return
>   the consolidated data or the full data and let AngularJS or Jquery
>   make the consolidation on the client?

You should always return a view model from your controller action containing only the required information to the client. This way, not only that you optimize bandwidth and network usage, but you make the life of the clients much easier. They no longer need to make complex data querying and projections but directly use the information that is provided to them under the form of a view model.

Conclusion: your controller actions should always take and pass specifically designed view models from/to views.

Comment: I see.So even in AJAX i should not make the client aware of more data than he needs a tthe time. If i need to get the analysis for every aggregation then this is a new AngularJS / Jquery call everytime?

Comment: No, never make the client aware of all the data. Only make it aware of what it needs. If you need to make multiple AJAX calls for different aggregation you might consider returning those aggregations as part of the initial view model. This would avoid you the cost of sending multiple AJAX request. Remember that it is better to make 1 AJAX request which returns larger payload rather than multiple AJAX requests returning small payloads. That's a golden rule of thumb that must be followed. I have seen people making AJAX requests in `for` loops in javascript which is just terrible.

Comment: Thanks again, and what i do if i want to return in one page 2 ViewModel classes with different data? For example i want to return production aggregated data and Sales aggregated data..

Comment: No, you never return 2 view models. You always return 1 view model. In your case this view model might contain 2 properties: one containing the aggregated production data and one for the sales data so that the client could access them directly.

Comment: This means that i create a ViewModel class that contains 2 other non-related between them classes?. And this could go on forever? I mean if i have a complex view with 5 different data groups i do the same? One view model class that has 5 different classes?

Comment: No, you never use your domain model classes in the view model. If a view model needs to contain some complex structure/property, this property should be another view model. Alternatively you could flatten the data in the view model. After all that's what the view model is for: project your domain data in an easy to use manner by the client. You are absolutely free to put whatever information is required by the client.

Comment: I meant to say that i create a separate viewmodel class for each domain class/classes with the necessary data i want and then i include them in a third viewmodel class that i sent to the view or expose in the api